# How to undo a reset (Git / TortoiseGit)?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I'm currently (the only one) working on a local repository being pushed remotely to my GitHub accounts. Today I could not find anything about the new code I wrote yesterday night so I was wondering what could went wrong or if I've done some mistake accidentally.

Now I'm inspecting my Reflog (using Tortoise Git).
As you can see from my [Reflog Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzHK2.png), a RESET occurred, which could explain why I "lost" the code. My question would be: is it possible to undo this reset in such a way to get all files as they were the moment right before resetting? If not possible, since everything is quite recent, is there any another way to achieve the same result?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Were the files committed before you issued the reset, or were they still uncommitted changes in your working folder?

Comment: Not right before the reset, which is the point I need to recover. Is there something cached in git for very recent changes?

Answer (score 0):

Undoing a reset highly depends on the type of reset and the working tree state.

When you performed a hard reset and you had uncommitted changes in your working tree, then these uncommitted changes are lost (unless you have backupped them before).

When you had no uncommitted changes, you can easily open the RefLog dialog, select the last commit/entry before the reset and open the context menu. Here you can create a new branch that then points to the state of the repository (index) before the reset. When you now open this branch in the log dialog, you can rebase it onto you old branch or cherry pick commits or what you would like to do.

Comment: How to know if it was hard reset or not? Is it possible to understand from the Reflog Screenshot I put in my question?

Comment: You can't see that with the RefLog.

Comment: You might be able to see it using the TortoiseGit logfile: %LOCALAPPDATA%\TortoiseGit\logfile.txt